# Remix: unable to deploy

Tags: remix, walletconnect

In remix when i try to deploy i keep getting this

```
URL: https://rpc.sepolia.org
Request body: {"method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{"from":"thisis my address","data":"some contract data","value":"0x0","gas":"0x1d399","type":"0x2","maxPriorityFeePerGas":"0x9502F900","maxFeePerGas":"0x95bdb604"}]}

Details: unknown account
Version: viem@1.2.12
```

The adress is ok, and shows up (with sepEth) on https://sepolia.etherscan.io/

Comment: Does the account have enough ethers to pay the transaction fees? You should get them from a faucet otherwise.